# VMware shared storage cluster isn't visible on all hosts

Tags: storage, cluster, vmware-vcenter

I have a trial Vcenter 5 + 2 esx 5, all still in trial period, meaning I have all features enabled.

I have created a LUN on my QNAP NAS, and added it as a cluster datastorage on my vcenter
[image]

however, when I want to move a client (even in shutdown state) I don't get the 'test' cluster as an option.

where can I should/start checking?

Comment: Are you trying to relocate where the VM is stored, or move the VM so that it runs on a different host, or both?

Comment: Do all of the ESXi hosts have access to the datastore in the Storage section of the Configuration tab?

Comment: @shanemadden no, I don't have the LUN mapped to every host. Is it really necessary? I only have 2 hosts now, but if I have 20, and I add a new storage cluster - do I need to go to each host to map it? seems weird.

Comment: In my experience, to migrate a VM from one ESX host to another, both hosts need to have visibility of the datastore.

Comment: @Saariko Yes, absolutely.  All hosts in the cluster must have access to shared storage.  With NFS storage, you'll need to add each mount manually to each host; with iSCSI or FC storage, a simple rescan can pick up new LUNs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving a client is called VMotion. Is that feature enabled on your trial? Also, you can only VMotion between hosts on the same datastore. If you want to move a host from one datastore to another, you need to use Storage VMotion, and that's even more expensive than the version with just VMotion.

Comment: vMotion / storage vMotion is only applicable for running VMs - Sarriko appears to have an issue even when the VM is powered off.

Comment: ESX 5 trial period - ALL features are enabled. And as @growse mentioned - I get the error even in shutdown mode.

Comment: @Saariko If you attempt to move a VM to a host that doesn't have access to the storage that the VM is stored on, without moving the VM's storage to something accessible to the new host, then it won't work.  You need to more thoroughly explain what you're attempting to do; how are you initiating the migration, and what options are you selecting in the migration wizard?